# Unity | Coroutine Speeding Up After Each Executions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

My coroutine to fade the player out after they die,

```
// Fade out ragdoll
IEnumerator RagdollFade()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    while (startingColour.a > 0.0f)
    {
        headSR.color = new Color(headSR.color.r, headSR.color.g, headSR.color.b, headSR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));
        bodySR.color = new Color(bodySR.color.r, bodySR.color.g, bodySR.color.b, bodySR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));
        leftArmSR.color = new Color(leftArmSR.color.r, leftArmSR.color.g, leftArmSR.color.b, leftArmSR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));
        rightArmSR.color = new Color(rightArmSR.color.r, rightArmSR.color.g, rightArmSR.color.b, rightArmSR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));
        leftLegSR.color = new Color(leftLegSR.color.r, leftLegSR.color.g, leftLegSR.color.b, leftLegSR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));
        rightLegSR.color = new Color(rightLegSR.color.r, rightLegSR.color.g, rightLegSR.color.b, rightLegSR.color.a - (Time.deltaTime / 1.5f));

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

speeds up after each execution.

For example, this first time the coroutine is called everything works fine and after 3 seconds the player is faded out. However, the next time it is called 3 seconds don't pass before the fade, the next time even less time, etc.

`startingColour` is set in the Start() function.

Comment: You never modify `startingColour.a` so you never leave the `while` loop?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz poorly worded, I do change it - the starting value is set in the start function

Comment: Are you sure you leave the while loop?

Comment: what is it supposed to do? Is `startingColour.a` changed anywhere else? Otherwise couldn't you simply use `while(true)`? And where are `headSR.color` etc reset? I mean once you faded them out .. do the stay faded out? In this case it shouldn't be strange that it is faster the second time. And as @LudovicFeltz says you probably never leave the while loop? so when you call `StartCoroutine` again you will have two concurrent routines running

Comment: @derHugo Basically, when the player dies I want their body to fade out. Because they are a ragdoll, I have to fade out each of the sections (ie head, body, etc). `while true`is a simpler way of writing this, my bad. I have tried resetting `headSR.color` both at the end of this coroutine and before it is called, but nothing changes. `headSR.color = startingColour;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try call `StopCoroutine()` before starting a new Coroutine. Possibly you have a few coroutines working at the same time.

Comment: Yep this was it, two coroutines were interfering with each other. Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your `startingColour.a` value is **always** bigger then `0` so the `while` loop never finishes and your coroutine just runs forever. Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

So if you start it a second time you now have both routines running parallel => now each frame you decrease the alphas by the double amount .. then triple .. etc. and it also doesn't wait the 3 seconds before the first called routines are already running the `while` loop so they continue to decrease the alphas.

---

You could use [`StopAllCoroutines`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html) or [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) in order to interrupt any still running routines when starting a new one. But that's actually more a kind of dirty workaround.

---

I would rather takle the actual issue and make sure your while loop returns which is currently unlikely to happen since you seem to not change `startColor.a` anywhere.

Or add a flag not allowing parallel routines at all like e.g.

```
private bool isFading;

IEnumerator RagdollFade()
{
    if(isFading) yield brake;

    // prevents other routines
    isFading = true;

    ...

    // reset the flag once routine is finished
    isFading = false;
}
```

---

Then I would also rather suggest to have one single `float` value you use for fading using [`Color.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html) like

```
private bool isFading;

// you can also use a fixed duration and not pass it as parameter
// but this way you are even more flexible
IEnumerator RagdollFade(float duration)
{
    if(isFading) yield brake;

    // prevents other routines
    isFading = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    // it is more performant to gather all required information beforehand

    headStartColor = headSR.color;
    bodyStartColor = bodySR.color;
    leftArmStartColor = leftArmSR.color;
    rightArmStartColor = rightArmSR.color;
    leftLegStartColor = leftLegSR.color;
    rightLegStartColor = rightLegSR.color;

    headTargetColor = new Color(headStartColor.r, headStartColor.g, headStartColor.b, 0f);
    bodyTargetColor = new Color(bodyStartColor.r, bodyStartColor.g, bodyStartColor.b, 0f);
    leftArmTargetColor = new Color(leftArmStartColor.r, leftArmStartColor.g, leftArmStartColor.b, 0f);
    rightArmTargetColor = new Color(rightArmStartColor.r, rightArmStartColor.g, rightArmStartColor.b, 0f);
    leftLegTargetColor = new Color(leftLegStartColor.r, leftLegStartColor.g, leftLegStartColor.b, 0f);
    rightLegTargetColor = new Color(rightLegStartColor.r, rightLegStartColor.g, rightLegStartColor.b, 0f);

    var passedTime = 0f;
    while (passedTime < duration)
    {
        // get the interpolation factor from 0 to 1
        var factor = passedTime / duration;
        // for adding additional ease-in and ease-out
        // factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        headSR.color = Color.Lerp(headStartColor, headTargetColor, factor);
        bodySR.color = Color.Lerp(bodyStartColor, bodyTargetColor, factor);
        leftArmSR.color = Color.Lerp(leftArmStartColor, leftArmTargetColor, factor);
        rightArmSR.color = Color.Lerp(rightArmStartColor, rightArmTargetColor, factor);
        leftLegSR.color = Color.Lerp(leftLegStartColor, leftLegTargetColor, factor);
        rightLegSR.color = Color.Lerp(rightLegStartColor, rightLegTargetColor, factor);


        // avoid overshooting
        passedTime += Mathf.Min(Time.deltatime, duration - passedTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    // reset the flag once routine is finished
    isFading = false;
}
```

This is more flexible and you can add ease-in and ease-out using whatever simple math you like.

Comment: Wow thanks man! I really appreciate you taking the time to write this out, I'll have a look and include this sort of stuff in the future. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: would you mind to accept my answer then? As said the one you accepted is more of a dirty workaround .. and was added after my post btw ;)

Comment: Haha, you've got 17.6k points man - I'm sure one tick doesn't hurt. Take my currently invisible upvote instead :D. Thanks again and have a great day :).

Comment: @derHugo Totally, agree with Wzrd. Your answer is amazing, but let's also give a chance to the new-comer :)

Comment: @GauravMall I agree with both of you supporting new comers .. but in the correct conditions ;) The quality of the other post is ... well ..

Comment: @derHugo Agree with you as well. Quality is top-notch. Well, the OP has his reasons. We can hope you get a lot of up-votes. Sometimes some answers are, well, failed tries. I also have two high-quality answers that don't even have upvotes. It's okay, what matters is that you learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved the problem, and it's completely my bad.

I realized that **ANOTHER** coroutine I had was interfering with the current one, so that's why `StopCoroutine()` and adding a fade check wasn't working.

Sorry guys for not including that in my question post, you would probably have been able to help me out more effectively.

**So for anyone who encounters strange routine behavior in the future, make sure two coroutines are not interfering with each other.**